# i have a problem with trying to open dhcpcd on rpi 4

Tags: pi-4

so when i open the wi-fi settings I get the warning "Error saving /etc/dhcpcd.conf".

i have tried nothing yet because I don't know what to do

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: What exactly do you do to "*open the wi-fi settings*". Maybe you need to do something with `sudo` to get the permission to modify `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

Comment: dhcpcd has nothing to do with WiFi. What are you doing?